# Audio recording during webRTC call on Android app

Tags: webrtc, restcomm

I am using restcomm android webRTC sdk for video calling 
https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk.

I want to start audio recording when WebRtc call is established, so that I could use raw audio data for some processing. The WebRtc call should be in parallel with my audio data processing. Since mic is not shared in Android I am unable to access microphone while the video call is happening.

Is it possible to get the audio data from the MediaStream or AudioTrack?

Comment: This is currently not supported in the SDK. For more information, please refer to https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/issues/115

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: I think this link involves every answer related to `Audio_Processing` whether it is *Pre-Processing* or *Post-Processing*: [Android_Audio_Processing_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC), You can also visit this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546599/10413749