# How to record microphone to more compressed format during WebRTC call on Android?

Tags: android, webrtc, android-audiorecord

I have an app calling using `WebRTC`. But during a call, I need to record microphone. `WebRTC` has an object `WebRTCAudioRecord` to record audio but the audio file is so large (`PCM_16bit`). I want to record but to a smaller size.

I've tried `MediaRecorder` but it doesn't work because `WebRTC` is recorded and `MediaRecorder` does not have permission to record while calling.

Has anyone done this, or have any idea that could help me?

Comment: Hi @Tan Pham  Can you plz share your WebRTCAudioRecord class here so it's help me record audio during webrtc call Android?

Comment: @vasupujy that class was in WebRTC library already. You can see here: [WebRtcAudioRecord](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/defc21e0aa6b090111d6bd8ffe43ddafcb657c7d/webrtc/modules/audio_device/android/java/src/org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioRecord.java)

Answer (score 1):

Webrtc is considered as comparatively much better **pre-processing** tool for **Audio** and **Video**.

Webrtc native development includes fully `optimized native C and C++` classes, In order to maintain wonderful **Speech Quality and Intelligibility** of audio and video which is quite interesting.

Visit Reference Link: https://github.com/jitsi/webrtc/tree/master/examples regularly.

---

As Problem states;

> I want to record but smaller size. I've tried MediaRecorder and it doesn't work because WebRtc is recorded and MediaRecorder has not permission to record while calling.

---

First of all, to `reduce or minimize` the **size** of your recorded data (audio bytes), you should look at different types of **speech codecs** which basically reduce the size of recorded data by maintaining `sound quality` at a level. To see different [voice codecs](https://www.gl.com/voice-codecs.html), here are well-known speech codecs as follows:

- [OPUS](http://opus-codec.org/)
- [SPEEX](https://www.speex.org/)
- [G7.11](https://www.voip-info.org/codecs/) (G-Series Speech Codecs)

As far as **size** of the audio data is concerned, it basically depends upon the **Sample Rate** and **Time** for which you record a chunk or audio packet.

```
Supppose time = 40ms ---then---> Reocrded Data = 640 bytes (or 320 short)

Size of recorded data is **directly proportional** to both Time and Sample rate.

Sample Rate = 8000 or 16000 etc. (greater the sample rate, greater would be the size)
```

To see in more detail visit: [fundamentals of audio data representation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Fundamentals_of_Data_Representation/Sampled_sound). But `Webrtc` mainly process `10ms` audio data for pre-processing in which packet size is reduced up to `160 bytes`.

---

Secondly,  If you want to use *multiple AudioRecorder* instances at a time, then it is practically impossible. As `WebRtc` is already recording from microphone then practically `MediaRecorder` instance would not perform any function as this answer depicts [audio-record-multiple-audio-at-a-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715505/android-record-multiple-audio-at-a-time). Webrtc has following methods to manage audio bytes such as;

```
 1. Push input PCM data into `ProcessCaptureStream` to process in place.
 2. Get the processed PCM data from `ProcessCaptureStream` and send to far-end.
 3. The far end pushed the received data into `ProcessRenderStream`.
```

I have maintained a complete tutorial related to audio processing using Webrtc, you can visit to see more details; [Android-Audio-Processing-Using-Webrtc](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC).

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts for the solution:

1. Get the raw PCM audio frames from webrtc
2. Save them to a local file in compressed size so that it can be played out later

For the first part you have to attach the `SamplesReadyCallback` while creating `audioDeviceManager` by calling the `setSamplesReadyCallback` method of `JavaAudioDeviceModule`. This callback will give you the raw audio frames captured by webrtc's AudioRecord from the mic.

For the second part you have to encode the raw frames and write into a file. Check out this sample from google on how to do it - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenrecord/ScreenInternalAudioRecorder.java#234