# Is there any function for custom audio source in webRTC c++?

Tags: c++, webrtc

I am using android app native code and I am using some audio file and audio processing. I need to send audio data (raw audio frame) to webRTC. But I am not able to find any API of webRTC to add custom audio source(not default audio source like mic).

I understand that I need to add AudioTrackInterface and for that I need to add AudioSourceInterface.

Comment: I think this link involves every answer related to `Audio_Processing` whether it is *Pre-Processing* or *Post-Processing*: [Android_Audio_Processing_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC), You can also visit this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546599/10413749

Answer (score 4):

This method is actual for version 66 of WebRTC. It is not so simple and maybe not clear, but it really works. I try to explain main idea:

I inherit `webrtc::AudioDeviceModule` and override some methods for emulate 'Virtual audio device' for virtual playout and recording. On calls I just call standard `AudioDeviceModule` base methods with some modifications:

> `int16_t PlayoutDevices()` => call base method, but return base + 1
>
> `int16_t RecordingDevices()` => return base + 1
>
> `int32_t PlayoutDeviceName` => return my virtual device name and GUID
>
> `int32_t RecordingDeviceName` => return my virtual device name and GUID
>
> `void SendFrameP` => return my virtual device audio data
>
> `void ReceiveFrameP` => use received audio data by my virtual device
>
> etc methods => just look at `webrtc::AudioDeviceModule` implementation.

Then you can use your own `AudioDeviceModule` as parameter to `webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory` function and provide audio data as recording device and receive data as playout device.